# Parâmetro varchar em Store Procedure

Tags: mysql, parâmetros, stored-procedures

Tenho uma store procedure no mysql da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nome_procedure(campo VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    SELECT id as id, campo as value
    FROM tabela
    etc etc etc...;
END $$
```

Entretanto, como o parâmetro que estou passando é do tipo VARCHAR, ele me retorna o nome do campo que eu passar no resultado. Ou seja, é como se eu houvesse feito o select assim:

```
SELECT id as id, 'nome_campo' as value
```

Mas o que eu gostaria era:

```
SELECT id as id, nome_campo_que_eu_passei as value
```

Como fazer este retorno ser correto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisará montar um SQL dinamicamente, utilizando `campo` como variável:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nome_procedure(campo VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    SET @temp1 = CONCAT('SELECT id as id, ', campo, ' as value FROM tabela etc etc etc');

    PREPARE stmt1 FROM @temp1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END $$
```

Comment: Obrigado, Augusto! Resolveu!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Os parâmetros em stored procedures podem ser de dois tipos distintos, de entrada (**IN**) ou de saída (**OUT**).

O tipo do parâmetro deve ser informado ao criar a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nome_procedure(IN campo VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    SELECT id as id, campo as value
    FROM tabela
    etc etc etc...;
END $$
```

Verifique também se o nome do seu parâmetro já não foi declarado como nome de uma coluna de determinada tabela.

Minha dica quanto a nomenclatura, para que não ocorra problemas, é utilizar uma nomenclatura de parâmetros padrão, como por exemplo `p_campo` ou `p_coluna`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nome_procedure(IN p_campo VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    SELECT id as id, campo as value
    FROM tabela
    WHERE campo = p_campo;
END
```

Este código retorna o id e o campo **de todas as tuplas da tabela que possuem o valor de campo igual ao parâmetro p_campo**.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!

Comment: Bacana, Anderson! Mas o retorno foi dizendo que não havia o campo de nome campo em minha tabela! Obrigado! :-)

Comment: Desculpe, acebei interpretando errado a sua dúvida.

Comment: Beleza, a solução do Augusto resolveu! Obrigado!